# how to update the nested data of elastic search?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, search, elasticsearch

i am new to elastic search. i have successfully setup elastic-search server and implemented ES package in laravel. now i can add data to elastic search, but the problem is how can i update a nested item value in a row?. i have added a screen shot of my data structure here [a link](https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/459604/538e3ac4-9c45-41d1-b979-f87f446aa600/586406-rZKGvrOngIpqmr3x/screen.jpeg)!

[image: a busy cat]

Now how can i update comment_id 1 with my desired content?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will be a little problematic.
You should be aware of the way elasticsearch [index arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#object-arrays).

So in your case you will get something like this:

```
{
  .
  . 
  "comments":{
     "id": [1,2,3],
     "comment": ["this is comment1", "this is comment2", "this is comment3"]
  }
}
```

So you loose the correlation between "id" and "comment".
If you like to keep this correlation you will need to define "comments" as "nested" in your mappings. look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html).

In order to update your nested document you will probebly need to use [scripted update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates).

If you will need to update a specific comment in the array, you can write a script that find it and replace it, or you can read the whole array, edit it and override the current array.

Comment: hi, what if we manage comments as separate "_type" ? then we can create search add easily right? or is there any problem if we set sub-data as separate type?

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion.

Comment: plz check this https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/459609/538e3ac4-9c45-41d1-b979-f87f446aa600/586406-RKzqXPH2UMye2zGb/screen.jpeg